# IE and Psuedo Elements not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am using `:before` and `:after` but they are not showing in IE10 and below.

Here is the link to the site: [wrdtempsite.com.au/da](http://wrdtempsite.com.au/da)

When viewing dev tools (F12) all of the css is struck through... ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post your code here? Specifically, the html and css of the elements what don't work well?

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem with IE9+. IE8 has partial support according to http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent.

Comment: can you provide the part of code in jsfiddle.net

Comment: I think you have a wrong html element inside your :before and :after functions. image tags are not allowed, they're rendered as text.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add empty CSS rule for `:hover` before adding rules for `:before` and `:after`

Check the below link, it deals with the same issue. hope it helps

[::after on :hover does not work in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321878/after-on-hover-does-not-work-in-ie)

[Why does IE10 require the presence of a p:hover {} rule for transitions to work on a pseudo element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015371/why-does-ie10-require-the-presence-of-a-phover-rule-for-transitions-to-work?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I had declared 0 0 no-repeat at the end; when I removed these it worked fine.

Thanks